# How do I update only *minor* version-bumps of installed Homebrew packages?

Tags: macos, sh, homebrew, versioning, semantic-versioning

I would like to filter `brew upgrade` (which, by default, upgrades *all* installed packages to their latest versions) to only automatically update the 'chaff' - any packages which saw minor bumps, for which I am too lazy to read changenotes or worry about.

This feature was [proposed but rejected](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3275) by the Homebrew team; the goal here is to script this externally to Homebrew so upstream interest isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this shell script to handle it for me. It requires [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (`brew install jq`) and the [semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver#install) package from npm.

```sh
brew upgrade $(
   brew outdated --json | \
      jq -r '(.formulae[] | [.name, .installed_versions[-1], .current_version]) | join(" ")' | \
      while read -r formula current new; do
         if (semver --range '~'$current $new >/dev/null);
            then >&2 echo "${formula}: $current --> $new"; echo "$formula"; fi
      done
)
```

My solution will invoke bare `brew upgrade` if there's no minor packages to upgrade, which will update everything else; be careful!